# Who made The Rings of Power?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

There are twenty magical Rings in the Tolkien's Middle Earth

> Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky,
>
> Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone,
>
> Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die
>
> One for the Dark Lord on his dark throne

The One Ring was forged by Sauron himself at Mount Doom. Who created the other Rings of Power?

Comment: I really recommend you read _The Silmarillion_, if you haven't already. It's a rough go, especially if you're more used to _The Hobbit_ or _The Lord Of The Rings_, but it has that information and a **ton** of stuff you'll recognize as back story to both Tolkien's other books. In addition, have you had a chance to look through the Appendices to _The Lord Of The Rings_? Appendices A, B, and F, in particular, give a lot more back story. They're sometimes dry, but very rewarding if you give them a chance!

Comment: Why is it that more rings of this nature could not be made again? Are there no elven smith's left with the capability? How are the rings "enchanted" with their magical properties to begin with if Sauron did not directly forge them?

Comment: @Toproller777 Eregion, the kingdom where they were made was destoyed shortly afterwards, in the War of the Elves and Sauron.  While a few survivors escaped to Rivendell, there is no evidence that any members of the Gwaith-i-Mírdain (group who made the rings) were among them.  Even if there were, the rings were made based on Sauron's (in disguise) teachings, which would add to the reluctance of making more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These were made by the Elven smiths of Eregion. The Seven and the Nine were made with Sauron's assistance, the Three were made by Celebrimbor himself, and the One was made by Sauron alone, in secret.

> It was in Eregion that the counsels of Sauron were most gladly received, for in that land the Noldor desired ever to increase the skill and subtlety of their works. Moreover they were not at peace in their hearts, since they had refused to return into the West, and they desired both to stay in Middle-earth, which indeed they loved, and yet to enjoy the bliss of those that had departed. Therefore they hearkened to Sauron, and they learned of him many things, for his knowledge was great. In those days the smiths of Ost-in-Edhil surpassed all that they had contrived before; and they took thought, and they made Rings of Power. But Sauron guided their labours, and he was aware of all that they did; for his desire was to set a bond upon the Elves and to bring them under his vigilance.
>
> Now the Elves made many rings; but secretly Sauron made One Ring to rule all the others, and their power was bound up with it, to be subject wholly to it and to last only so long as it too should last. And much of the strength and will of Sauron passed into that One Ring; for the power of the Elven-rings was very great, and that which should govern them must be a thing of surpassing potency; and Sauron forged it in the Mountain of Fire in the Land of Shadow. And while he wore the One Ring he could perceive all the things that were done by means of the lesser rings, and he could see and govern the very thoughts of those that wore them.
>
> But the Elves were not so lightly to be caught. As soon as Sauron set the One Ring upon his finger they were aware of him; and they knew him, and perceived that he would be master of them, and of an that they wrought. Then in anger and fear they took off their rings. But he, finding that he was betrayed and that the Elves were not deceived, was filled with wrath; and he came against them with open war, demanding that all the rings should be delivered to him, since the Elven-smiths could not have attained to their making without his lore and counsel. But the Elves fled from him; and three of their rings they saved, and bore them away, and hid them.
>
> Now these were the Three that had last been made, and they possessed the greatest powers. Narya, Nenya, and Vilya, they were named, the Rings of Fire, and of Water, and of Air, set with ruby and adamant and sapphire; and of all the Elven-rings Sauron most desired to possess them, for those who had them in their keeping could ward off the decays of time and postpone the weariness of the world. But Sauron could not discover them, for they were given into the hands of the Wise, who concealed them and never again used them openly while Sauron kept the Ruling Ring. Therefore the Three remained unsullied, for they were forged by Celebrimbor alone, and the hand of Sauron had never touched them; yet they also were subject to the One.
> <sub>*The Silmarillion*, "Of the Rings Of Power and the Third Age (in which these tales come to their end)"</sub>

Answer (score 3):

SQB is correct but let me note The Lord of the Rings itself tells you (Council of Elrond):

> Then all listened while Elrond in his clear voice spoke of Sauron and the Rings of Power, and their forging in the Second Age of the world long ago. A part of his tale was known to some there, but the full  tale to none, and many eyes were turned to Elrond in fear and wonder as he told of the Elven-smiths of Eregion and their friendship with Moria, and their eagerness for knowledge, by which Sauron ensnared them. For in that time he was not yet evil to behold, and they received his aid and grew mighty in craft, whereas he learned all their secrets, and betrayed them, and forged secretly in the Mountain of Fire the One Ring to be their master. But Celebrimbor was aware of him, and hid the Three which he had made; and there was war, and the land was laid waste, and the gate of Moria was shut.
>   [...]
>   For in the day that Sauron first put on the One, Celebrimbor, maker of the Three, was aware of him, and from afar he heard him speak these words, and so his evil purposes were revealed.